# String in a list doesn't accept assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

```
import os
f=os.popen('df -h')
drive_usage=f.read()
drive_usage.split()
email('test','Critical! Drive usage is very high!')
for x in range(4,len(drive_usage)-1,6):
    s2 = drive_usage[x][0:len(drive_usage[x])]
    drive_usage[x] = s2
    if drive_usage[x]>90:
        #email admin
```

This code should read the output of `df -h` on an ubuntu 12.04 server, split the output of the command into a list, and then trim the '%' character off, so that the drive usage can be used as a comparator in an if statement. Then, if it's above 90%, it should email the server admins.

However, `drive_usage[x] = s2` triggers the `'str' object does not support item assignment`. To my knowledge, this should not be triggering, as that line should be accessing a string in a list, not a character in a string. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: the line `drive_usage.split()` should probably be `drive_usage = drive_usage.split()`

Comment: Thanks, @rick Teachey ! That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
drive_usage.split()
```

should be:

```
drive_usage = drive_usage.split()
```

As the string method `.split()` returns a list, whereas you are expecting it to replace the string with a list of its parts which doesn't happen.